# SQL select insert into trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
USE [BASE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trig1]
   ON [dbo].[Report]
   for Update
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO DeclarationApprover ( ApproverLevel,Approver)
    select(9,'asd')
    from inserted

END
```

ApproverLevel and Approver both are nvarchar

My query is giving the below error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.
>   select(9,'asd')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses in your select clause:

```
INSERT INTO DeclarationApprover (ApproverLevel, Approver)
SELECT 9, 'asd'
FROM INSERTED;
```

You should not need to use an actual tuple in your select clause; just use a CSV list of literal values instead.

Actually, you should not even need `FROM INSERTED`, since you are not actually using any of the columns in that record, so the following should work:

```
INSERT INTO DeclarationApprover (ApproverLevel, Approver)
SELECT 9, 'asd';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  i will accept your answer (You can accept an answer in 8 minutes).
and another question if you dont mind,
when my trigger works, it updates 2 row with same information.
what would be the reason for it.

Comment: Well your trigger does the _same_ insert for _any_ record, which is probably the reason.  So, you maybe you intended some other logic.

Comment: That is not possible AFAIK.  Updating a single row should only ever result in at most one record being inserted.